# Separate fields with a multi-character delimiter using awk

Tags: awk

I wanted to print the fields in the line which is delimited by `|~^`. I tried many ways, but am unable to print the fields using `awk`. Below is the file content for reference.

Input

```
H|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05|~^10.00
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05|~^20.00
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05|~^30.00
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06|~^100.00
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06|~^15.00
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06|~^10.00
T|~^20200425|~^6|~^185.00
```

I need to separate the fields based on `|~^` delimiter using `awk`. I tried

```
cat input |grep "^T"|awk -F '|~^' '{print $2}'
```

but it's returning null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Accept AdminBee's answer. It is his award for the best answer that satisfies your conditions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is related to the following statement in the (GNU) `awk` manpage [1]:

> If FS is a single character, fields are separated by that character.  If FS is  the
>    null  string, then each individual character becomes a separate field. *Otherwise, FS is expected to be a full regular expression*.

Since your field delimiting pattern contains characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions (the `|` and the `^`), you need to escape them properly. Because of the way `awk` interprets variables (string literals are parsed *twice*), you would need to specify that using *double backslashes*, as in

```
awk -F '\\|~\\^' '{print $2}' input.txt
```

Resulting output for your example:

```
20200425
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
20200425
```

To consider only those lines starting with `T`, use

```
awk -F '\\|~\\^' '/^T/ {print $2}' input.txt
```

or alternatively, by selecting only lines where a certain field (here, the first field) has a value of `T`:

```
awk -F '\\|~\\^' '$1=="T" {print $2}' input.txt
```

Result for your example in both cases

```
20200425
```

Notice that in general, the combined use of `awk`, `grep` and `sed` is rarely necessary. Furthermore, all these tools can directly access files, so using `cat` to feed them the text to process is also unnecessary.

[1]: As an (unrelated) side note: The part with the "null string" does not work on all Awk variants. The GNU Awk manual states *"This is a common extension; it is not specified by the POSIX standard".*

Answer (score 1):

Found an example [here](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/154945-awk-multiple-character-delimiter.html) and slightly modified it:

Another way is to replace it with other delimiter character and use it instead:

```
cat infile |sed "s/|~^/,/g"
H,20200425,abcd,sum
R,abc,2019-03-05,10.00
R,abc,2019-03-05,20.00
R,abc,2019-03-05,30.00
R,abc,2019-03-06,100.00
R,abc,2019-03-06,15.00
R,abc,2019-03-06,10.00
T,20200425,6,185.00

$ cat infile |sed "s/|~^/,/g" | cut -d',' -f2-3
20200425,abcd
abc,2019-03-05
abc,2019-03-05
abc,2019-03-05
abc,2019-03-06
abc,2019-03-06
abc,2019-03-06
20200425,6
```

`2` after `-f` is starting column, `3` is ending column.