# sum of the decimal values upto 5 decimal points in shell preferably awk

Tags: shell

## File1:

```
H|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^1000123.34567|~^2018-04-12T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^111930.02876|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^2112320.028|~^2018-10-24T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^12230.0809|~^2018-09-11T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^3076543789.00878|~^2018-08-05T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^156655.0389|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^10453.0489|~^2018-04-08T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^20654.0907|~^2018-07-23T12:33:52.27|
T|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^3424365.66183
```

### File2:

```
H|~^20200426|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-07T12:33:52.27|~^10.347|~^2018-04-12T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-08T12:33:52.27|~^111.06|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^2112.08|~^2018-10-24T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^12230.089|~^2018-09-11T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-04T12:33:52.27|~^30769.078|~^2018-08-05T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^155.09|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-03T12:33:52.27|~^10.89|~^2018-04-08T12:33:52.27|
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^206.07|~^2018-07-23T12:33:52.27|
T|~^20200426|~^abcd|~^155604.704
```

I need to get the sum of the total amounts in the 4th field for the record starts from 'R'. 
I wanted sum of amounts of all the rows to be stored in a variable. After sum it should capture all the decimal points correctly.
Trailer record starts with "T" has the sum output in the last field for refernce.

Comment: Is this data the same as the data in [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585869/sum-of-the-amounts-in-a-file-should-be-stored-as-single-value-in-an-shell-variab)?  In that case, you may want to mention that the numbers may contain up to 31 digits? Such a number requires special handling as it by far exceeds what can be stored in a 32-bit (or even 64-bit) value. You need a variable with at least 100-bit, which `awk` does not provide. In comments to my answer there, you also mention that you need to preserve 5 digits of accuracy after the decimal point.

Comment: You also appear to have quite a bad record of _accepting answers_. You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks I 'm new to this community, I will follow the link in accepting/voting the answers given. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

separator were a challenge

I came up with

```
awk -F '[|^]' '$1 == "R" { s+=$7 ; } $1 == "T" {  printf "Sum %.5f\n",s}'
```

giving

```
Sum 3079968154.67061
```

where

- `-F '[|^]'` tell awk to use either `|` or `^` as filed separator
- `$1 == "R" { s+=$7 ; }` sum in `s` 7th field if first is `R`
- `$1 == "T" {  printf "Sum %.5f\n",s}` print total, including 5 digit

---

to adjust **output** precision, one can use a cryptic printf(3) option

```
awk -v prec=3 -F '[|^]' '$1 == "R" { s+=$7 ; } 
     $1 == "T" { print ; printf "Sum %.*f\n",prec,s}'
```

giving

```
Sum 3079968154.671
```

where

- `-v prec=3` give precision
- `*` in `"Sum %.*f\n"` tell printf to use arg as precision for %f.

precision can be computed.

```
awk  -F '[|^]' '$1 == "R" { s+=$7 ; } 
                $1 == "T" { print ; 
                            prec=length($7)-index($7,".");  
                            printf "t:%s, Sum %.*f\n",$7,prec,s}'
```

giving for the two sample file

```
T|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^3424365.66183
t:3424365.66183, Sum 3079968154.67061

T|~^20200426|~^abcd|~^155604.704
t:155604.704, Sum 45604.704
```

Note that it won't work for negative precision (prec=-2 to round to hundreds).

Note on precision :

according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format precision is 52 bits, or about 15 digits. Number above is likely an approximation of exact sum (due to `3076543789.00878` being 15 digit wide).

Comment: Hey @Archmar, Thanks for the solution, In your code decimal points would be always 5. But my use case can be changed as I mentioned it is up to 5 points. This is dynamic, next file may have the sum with 2 points.  I think the above could not suffice that

Comment: note that sum is computed for whatever input floating number is, you can print with any precision though.

Comment: @Archmar, I have updated the question, I have multiple files with different amounts, In 1st file after sum amount went up to 5 decimal points. But in 2nd file sum value is 3 decimal points. So I wanted the sum value as same as it is present in the trailer last field. I should not restrict my sum value to certain decimal points always.

Comment: to sum up, you want to verify total is correct ?

Comment: I mainly concerned about the sum part alone. I can manually look the trailer and check whether sum of all the amounts are matching with trailer field.

Comment: To keep it simple when I add 2.33+3.45 I should get the sum as 5.78 but with same code in the new input file I have 2.33045+3.456 I should get the sum as 5.78645.

Comment: OK, let's get back to basic. 1) post a question with all details at once. 2) do not forget to include what you have tried.

Comment: @Archemar The issue of the separators is covered in a [different question by the same user ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582772/separate-fields-with-a-multi-character-delimiter-using-awk?noredirect=1&lq=1) ;)

Comment: @Archemar, Thanks a lot for the solution. Sorry I was new to this community and follow the basics hereafter.

Answer (score 1):

If by

> capture all the decimal points correctly

you mean that you want the sums to be printed with the maximum precision of any of their terms, then you will likely need to track the precision - for example:

```
$ awk -F'\\|~\\^' '
    $1=="R"{sum+=$4; if(match($4,/\.[0-9]+/) && RLENGTH-1>p) {p=RLENGTH-1}} 
    END{printf "%.*f\n",p,sum}
  ' File2
  45604.704

$ awk -F'\\|~\\^' '
    $1=="R"{sum+=$4; if(match($4,/\.[0-9]+/) && RLENGTH-1>p) {p=RLENGTH-1}} 
    END{printf "%.*f\n",p,sum}
  ' File1
  3079968154.67061
```

There may be a better way to extract the precisions - a regex match was just the first that came to mind.